# It is possible to configure more than one haproxy in different machines to listen to same request?

Tags: centos, haproxy, centos7

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a cluster of haproxy, so if the haproxy machine fails, another haproxy gets the job done.

I tried to change the frontend configuration to listen to other machine request but haproxy does not start up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually accomplished by combining HAproxy with keepalived.  HAproxy handles the load balancing, keepalived handles the HA failover.

To clarify, only one HAproxy instance is active at a time, but if the primary node fails, the other takes over.